# Use Materialize in TypeScript and angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I installed @types/materialize-css for use in Angular/TypeScript but I can't inicializate the 'M', any idea how can I do this? I don't want to use angular-material!

Comment: have you installed `materialize-css`? @types/materialize-css is just for types, which don't exist at runtime

Comment: of course, I have install materialize and @types in my angular proyect.

Answer (score 0):

Use this package NPM: [angular2-Materialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize-v1) in place of @types/materialize